# How to use tinymce plugin?

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, cakephp-1.3, wysiwyg

I have tried many times to use this plugin and I failed.
I am following documentation, but it does not work for me.
I am posting the simple code here, to know what wrong I am doing.

1-I put this plugin in this folder app/plugins

2- I add TinyMce helper to articles_controller

```
<?php

    class ArticlesController extends AppController {
        // good practice to include the name variable
        var $name = 'articles';

        // load any helpers used in the views
        var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form','TinyMce.TinyMce');

        /**
         * index()
         * main index page of the formats page
         * url: /formats/index
         */
      function index(){
          // get all formats from database where status = 1
       $articles = $this->Article->find("all") ;

        $this->set('articles', $articles);

        }


        function admin_add() {
                    // if the form data is not empty
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            // initialise the format model
         $this->Article->save($this->data);

                // set a flash message
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Format has been saved');
                // redirect
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            } else {
                // set a flash message
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Format could not be saved. Please, try again.','default', array('class' => 'flash_bad'));
            }
        }




    }
?>
```

3- in the view file articles/admin_add.ctp I added the editor

```
// i think the problem in this code
<?php $this->TinyMce->editor(array(

'theme' => 'advanced'
        ));   ?>
<div class="formats form">

<?php echo $form->create('Article');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a article</legend>
        <?php
        // create the form inputs
           echo $this->Form->input('title');
           echo $this->Form->input('content');      ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end('Add');?>
</div>

<ul class="actions">
    <li><?php echo $html->link('List Articles', array('action'=>'index'));?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You put what in the plugin folder?? tinyMce is not a plugin... is js. you may be using is a helper... you have to put the tinymce on the js in and then the helper to the helpers folders (in views) and then you may use it. Also you may need to do echo of $this->TinyMce->editor....

Comment: api55:  Tiny MCE is a plugin: http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/tinymce

Comment: api55  you are wrong .. there is a plugin in cakephp ..this is the url http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/tinymce

Comment: Dave, Serr, the problem is that TinyMCE has the concept of 'plugins' hence api55's confusion. It looks like the problem you have Serr is with the Cake plugin (either it's implementation or how you are using it). Do you need to also install TinyMCE somewhere or is it bundled with the Cake plugin? It would also be helpful to know what is actually happening more than "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to put tinymce files into your js assets
2. Then you have to add  into  section of your layout.
3. Then you'll need to init tinymce according to example provided on tinymce website (ex: [full tinymce layout](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)) and configure it according to your requirements.

I'd personally would not rely on such cake plugins, when actions required to get things working are not many and they are simple enough.